# How to display a scaled down GL ES texture without clamp or repeat on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview

I am currently rendering a camera preview using GL ES 2.0 on android to a SurfaceTexture, rendering it with opengl, then transferring it to a media codec's input surface to for recording. It is displayed to the user in a surface view and by setting that surface view's aspect ratio  the camera preview is not distorted based on screen size.

The recording is in portrait, but at some point the incoming texture will start coming in landscape, at which point I'd like to zoom out and display it as a "movie" stretched wide to fit to the edge of the screen horizonatally with **black bars** on  the top and bottom to maintain the aspect ratio of the texture.

The [drawing code in onDrawFrame is pretty simple](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/blob/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/gl/TextureManager.java). The link has the rest of the setup code  for shaders and the like but it's just setting up a triangle strip to draw.

```
private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
        // X, Y, Z, U, V
        -1.f, -1.f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
        1.f, -1.f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
        -1.f,  1.f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
        1.f,  1.f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
};
    public static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
                "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
                "}\n";

private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];


    public TextureManager() {
    mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

    mTriangleHalfVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            mTriangleVerticesHalfData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mTriangleHalfVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesHalfData).position(0);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
}

    onDrawFrame(){
    mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
    GLES20.glFinish();`
}
```

Things I've tried that haven't quite worked: Scaling mMVPMatrix or mSTMatrix to zoom in. I can zoom in, so I can get the "center slice" of the landscape video to display without distortion, but this cuts off a huge 40% portion of the video, so it isn't a great solution. Zooming out by scaling these matricies causes the texture to repeat the pixel on the edge because of the clamp to edge behavior.

Halving the x,y,z parts of mTriangleVerticesData gives *some* of the desired behavior as seen in the screenshot below, exact aspect ratio aside. The center part of the picture is halved and centered, as expected. However, the texture is repeated to the left, right, and bottom, and there is distortion to the top left. What I *want* is the center to be as it is, with black/nothing surrounding it.

I could scale out then translate mMVPMatrix or mSTMatrix and then change my shader to display black for anything outside (0,1) but eventually I want to overlay multiple textures on top of one another, like a full size background and partial size foreground texture. To do this I must eventually figure out how to only display a texture in a portion of the available space, not just manipulate the texture so it looks like that's what's happening.

Thanks for reading all that. Any help, suggestions, or wild guesses are appreciated.

[image: Halving the x,y,z values of mTriangleVerticesData]

Comment: You could change the viewport instead of modifying the transformations. What you're trying to do sounds somewhat similar to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421262/opengl-viewport-distortion/32424138#32424138.

Comment: FWIW, the image looks more like GPU tiling artifacts than texture repeat. Are you erasing the background? If not, what happens if you add a `glClear()` call?

Comment: @fadden You are correct. Uncommenting out GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); fixes the problem. I guess it was commented out because it was unnecessary when dealing with one texture stretched. If you submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @sbaar: done. And yes, the clear is unnecessary when the rect fills the screen. For some tests I actually clear it to green first so that any untouched pixels stand out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated image chunks look like GPU tiling artifacts, not texture repeating.  Add a `glClear()` call to erase the background.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem what you are looking for is a "fit" system to get the correct frame of your element. It would mean for instance you are having a `100x200` image and you want to display it in a frame of `50x50`. The result should then be seeing the whole image in rectangle `(25, 0, 25, 50)`. So the resulting frame must respect the image ratio (`25/50 = 100/200`) and original frame boundaries must be respected.

To achieve this generally you need to compare the image ratio and the target frame ratio: `imageRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight` and `frameRatio = frameWidth/frameHeight`. Then if image ratio is larger then the frame ratio it means you need black borders on top and bottom while if the frame ratio is larger then you will see black borders on left and right side.

So to compute the target frame:

```
imageRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight
frameRatio = frameWidth/frameHeight
if(imageRatio > frameRatio) {
    targetFrame = {0, (frameHeight-frameWidth/imageRatio)*.5, frameWidth, frameWidth/imageRatio} // frame as: {x, y, width, height}
}
else {
    targetFrame = {(frameWidth-frameHeight*imageRatio)*.5, 0, frameHeight*imageRatio, frameHeight} // frame as: {x, y, width, height}
}
```

In your case the image width and height are the ones received from the stream; frame width and height are from your target frame which seems to be a result from matrices but for full screen case that would simply be values from glOrtho if you use it. The target frame should then be used to construct the vertices positions so you get exactly correct vertex data to display the full texture.

I see you use matrices to do all the computation in your case and the same algorithm may be used to be converted to matrix but I discourage you to do so. You seem to be over-abusing matrices which makes your code completely unmaintainable. I suggest in your case you keep to "ortho" projection matrix, use frames to draw textures and only use matrix scale and translations where it makes sense to do so.

Comment: It turns out glClear was what needed to be done, but this answer helps me in my step, so thank you. Also, that code I linked to wasn't written by me, but I think all the matrix shenanigans are neccesary because the texture may come in from the surface as mirrored or upside down, etc.

Comment: @sbaar: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595493/what-does-the-return-value-of-surfacetexture-gettransformmatrix-mean-who-can-ex