# VirtualDisplay.Callback onPause Not Called

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

I'm trying to deal with some timing issues I've seen with a `VirtualDisplay` as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209004/resize-surface-when-resizing-virtualdisplay) and I decided to use a `VirtualDisplay.Callback` to see if it would potentially fix my timing issues.

Only problem is that my callback never receives `onPause` when I call `virtualDisplay.setSurface(null)`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/VirtualDisplay.Callback.html#onPaused()) states that it should, but it does not. My handler is not in a tight loop, other methods in the `VirtualDisplay.callback` are called on `VirtualDisplay` start up. It just seems like the documentation is incorrect.

Anyone know how to get the callback called when the surface is set to null?